# Access Mac OS X folder from Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, networking, network-shares, file-sharing

How can I access a Mac OS X folder from Ubuntu Desktop (10.04) over the network?

Comment: Are you trying to access a folder on an OS X Client or Server?  Does Ubuntu see the OS X machine you are attempting to connect to?  Does it see the drive?  Does it see the folder?  Is the OS X folder on a OS X client drive that is HFS+ formatted?

Comment: As you haven't answered any of the questions, did the answer provided work for you?

Answer (score 1):

in Mac - export the folder via NFS (edit `/etc/exports`)

mount it in Ubuntu manual with `mount` or auto - edit `/etc/fstab`

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=323105

This recommends you load some files from the repository and make sure that journaling is OFF if you are going to have Ubuntu write to the drive.  In OS X go to System Preferences, Sharing, and checkmark all the services you want shared from OS X.

Comment: Ubuntu will never be writing to (or reading from) the drive if it's over the network, so disabling journaling is not required.